# How to create multisite solution in SXA 1.6 with different themes

Tags: sxa, multisite

We have created master site using `SXA 1.6` in `Sitecore 9.0.1`.

We are aiming to have different sites for different "brands" based on this master site.

We want to reuse content from the master site as much as possible and only change content slightly (like changing some banners and change text a bit on couple of places) and also create a theme to have different look and feel.

Questions:

1. What is the best practice here with SXA?
2. How to create multisite in this case?
3. Do we need some configuration changes or it can be purely managed in Sitecore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to do any configuration in Sitecore configs. Add the domain binding in IIS, do the host entry.. Then all you need to do is update the hostname and other details at site specific setting item.

You will find your site host setting at below path in Sitecore.
/sitecore/content/**Your Tenant**/**Your Site**/Settings/Site Grouping/**Your Site Host setting**.

[image]

You will find all the site configuration parameters at the Site Grouping.

You can Clone the Site which will create new Theme and update all the reference to Partial Designs.

[image]

Comment: This is not answering the scenario - "We want to reuse content from the master site as much as possible and only change content slightly (like changing some banners and change text a bit on couple of places) and also create a theme to have different look and feel." Please update your answer with example on how to create sites from existing one with using different theme

Comment: Apologies, I might be confused but you can achieve it using Clone Site option under same Tenant (right click on master site > Scripts option > Clone Site), It will take some time and You will have separate Theme and all reference will get updated with new clone site. Hope this will give answer to you query..

Comment: NSP - Please update your answer and I will aprove it

Answer (score 0):

You can store common items into one place and reference those items in all the sites. After creating the one site, clone it and create new site which will create new theme (static resources) for customization.